# Conditional currency decimals formatting with NumberFormatter

Tags: php, laravel, number-formatting

Is there a way to format currency conditionally depending on number of decimals?
For example :

**CHF 1'200.00    becomes CHF 1'200.-**

**CHF 1'200.2     becomes CHF 1'200.20**

**CHF 1'200.20    becomes CHF 1'200.20**

MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS attribute will set it all to .00, which solves 2nd and 3rd case, but will not solve the first one.

```
  $formatter->setAttribute(\NumberFormatter::MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS, 2);
```

Is there a way to do that? Or at least format decimals as subscript, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I see is to set the settings for the `NumberFormatter` based on a condition and then adding `.-` if the result is a whole number.

```php
// Check if we have a decimal that isn't .00 and adjust settings accordingly.
if (round($value, 2) == round($value, 0)) {
    $formatter->setAttribute(\NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS, 0);
} else {
    $formatter->setAttribute(\NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS, 2);
}

// Format the number
$formattedValue = $formatter->formatCurrency($value, 'CHF');

// Add '.-' if we have a whole number.
if (strpos($formattedValue, '.') === false) {
    $formattedValue .= '.-';
}
```

This should cover the cases in your question:

- `1200.00` -> `CHF 1'200.-`
- `1200` -> `CHF 1'200.-`
- `1200.20` -> `CHF 1'200.20`
- `1200.2` -> `CHF 1'200.20`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression replace with a strictly-formatted value where decimals are always included to replace the zero padded values with a custom ending and will work with various locales that have different monetary separators.

```php
function customCurrencyFormat(
    \NumberFormatter $formatter,
    string $currency,
    string|int|float $value
): string {
    // Ensure there are at least and no more than 2 fractional digits
    $formatter->setAttribute(\NumberFormatter::MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS, 2);
    $formatter->setAttribute(\NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS, 2);
    // Get the locale's monetary separator (usually , or .)
    $monetarySep = $formatter->getSymbol(
        \NumberFormatter::MONETARY_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL
    );
    // Replace zero padded endings (like .00) with the separator symbol followed
    // by a dash.
    $formattedValue = preg_replace(
        '/' . preg_quote($monetarySep) . '0+(?=([^0-9]+$|$))/',
        $monetarySep . '-',
        $formatter->formatCurrency($value, $currency)
    );
    return $formattedValue;
}

customCurrencyFormat($formatter, 'CHF', '634598'); // CHF 634’598.-
customCurrencyFormat($formatter, 'CHF', '3254636.4'); // CHF 3’254’636.40
```

This function will work even if you switch to other locales with different separators and currencies. Note that this could become confusing for some since it appears like a negative value.

Also note that if you use PHP earlier than 8.0 you may need to replace the type hint on the function's last `$value` parameter to `mixed` since earlier versions don't support union types.